# Vue doesn't rerender list even when using set

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I made a list that each item could be removable and my code looked like this:

Template

```
                    <template v-for="(timeFrame, index) in form.timeFrames">
                        
                        <el-form-item >
                                <el-button @click="removeTimeFrame(index)">
                                    <i class="el-icon-remove"></i>
                                </el-button>
                            </el-form-item>
                    </template>
```

Js:

```
removeTimeFrame(index = 0) {
            this.$set(this.form, 'timeFrames', this.form.timeFrames.filter((_, i) => index !== i));
}
```

Somehow the list doesn't rerender until I add an new item to the list. Does anybody know what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

templates in Vue need a top level element wrapping their content, so you shouldn't assign the `v-for` directly to the template tag, but instead create a `div` inside the template tag and either add `v-for` to the `el-form-item` component or wrap it in another `div`-tag.

Additionally, every element in a `v-for` loop should contain a key. If you do not plan to reorder or delete elements from the loop, the `index`-value of each element is fine for this. Seeing your example I suspect that a unique identifier, such as a randomly generated unique id, might work better for your use case.